# Laravel global scope for users causing "Maximum function nesting level" error

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a few user `roles`:

- Admin
- Owner
- Manager

I also have a model called `Company`. All other models (including the `User` model) have a `company_id` attribute. I want to create a global scope which scopes everything to the `company_id` EXCEPT for users with the `Admin` role. Admins should be able to see everything, regardless of which company the model is for.

I am getting the following error when visiting any page in my application:

> Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Here is my scope code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class CompanyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role != 'Admin') {
            $builder->where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I am applying the scope:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\CompanyScope;
use App\Traits\ColumnFillable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, ColumnFillable;

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

Here is another model I am using the scope on:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\CompanyScope;
use App\Traits\ColumnFillable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lead extends Model
{
    use ColumnFillable;

    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array',
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it is creating an endless loop when Laravel calls the `auth()` function? How do I prevent this without using local scopes?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue by moving the conditional statement into the `boot` method rather than inside the scope class:

```
    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role != 'Admin') {
        static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
    }
```